# 'float' object has no attribute 'exp' in spyder python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, spyder

```
import numpy as np  
from scipy import interpolate  
import pylab as py  
import pandas as pd  

def func(x1):  
    return x*np.exp(-5.0*x1**2)  
dataset=pd.read_excel('Messwerte_FIBRE1.xlsx')  
dataset=dataset.drop([0])  
index=[1]  
index2=[9]  
x=dataset.iloc[:, index]     
y=dataset.iloc[:, index2]  
x1=np.array(x)  
y1=np.array(y)  
fvals=func(x1)
```

File "C:/Users/Windows 10/.spyder-py3/RBF.py", line 10, in func
    return x*np.exp(-5.0*x1**2)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'
Any1 can help me to solve this problem?
[Here is the png of my textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHb0O.png)

Comment: would you mind providing how is your `'Messwerte_FIBRE1.xlsx'`is?

Comment: You can see in above question again. In bottom I have attached a snapshot of my Excel file

Comment: would you mind explaining more what you want to achieve with this logic? At first, it seems that somehow you have assigned a float to `np`.

Comment: I have solved the problem by changing these two lines:  x1=np.array(x,dtype=float)    
y1=np.array(y,dtype=float)

Answer (score 1):

> `np.exp(...)`
>
> 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'

This means that you likely have redefined the name `np`, and now it's a floating-point number and not the `numpy` module any more.

Look around your code for `np = ...`.

Comment: I think problem lies here:      return x*np.exp(-5.0*x1**2)